# jquery mobile send value in link and get in multipages file

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-mobile

I want to use a single file with multiple pages.
In the `#first` page I have a link to another page with a value sent via `GET`:

```
<a href='#second?ID=10'>
```

And when triggered, it should show the second page and write the value with php:

```
<div data-role="page" id="second"> 
<div data-role="header" data-add-back-btn="true">
    <h1>Second page</h1>
</div>
<div data-role="content">   
  <?php
  $ID = $_GET["ID"];
  echo $ID;
?>
</div>
</div>
```

It seems that the php code isn't run when the second page is loaded.
Is there any easy way to do this?

Comment: use `pagecontainerbeforechange` to read url and then `pagecontainershow` to do whatever you want http://plnkr.co/edit/pD0EB3DtzlVLPLdOsqwg

Comment: You can use a global javascript variable.